# Button inside childview of ExpandableListview is not working

Tags: android

I have plus,minus button and one count textview for each childview of expandable listview. when i click the plus or minus button the count should be display. i was tried with setOnclickListener and also with custom listener. but it's not working properly.
Please, help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

inside adapter class:

```
        ViewHolder.mMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myInterface.myClick(listPosition,expandedListPosition,view,ViewHolder.mPlus,ViewHolder.mMinus,ViewHolder.mCount);
            }
        });
```

public void  setItem(MyInterface myInterface)
    {
        this.myInterface=myInterface;

```
}
public interface MyInterface
{
    void myClick(int listposition, int expandedlistposition, View v,Button plus,Button minus,TextView count);
}
```

inside Activity:

```
@Override
public void myClick(int listposition, int expandedlistposition, View v, Button plus, Button minus, TextView count) {
    old_count[listposition][expandedlistposition]--;
    count.setText(String.valueOf(old_count[listposition][expandedlistposition]));
}
```

Comment: post your code snippet and logcat, have you tried  googling..?

Comment: yes i posted, i tried in google also.@nobalG

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code of what you want manage it according to your requirements ! Enjoy :)
[Expandable List View Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

it should be in the getChildView()

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(_context,"text clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: i was already studied this tutorial. it was very helpful. but, i have three views (plus button, minus button and count textview) inside childview. i want to trigger the buttons onclick of that. and show the count.

Comment: bro check out the answer i have tested it .... edited in the code of the link for you it working now ...

Comment: thanks @nightcoder .. i was tried this also bro. Assume,i have 10 number of child views  if i click plus or minus button the particular textview should get increment or decrement.. but it is not working like that. instead, when i click the button in one child the count gets increment or decrement in another child textview.. however, thanks for your kind reply bro..

Comment: I think you have to share your code... Expandable adapter class and main class .. so it would be easy to understand your problem

Comment: thanks @nightcoder. now, i found the solution it's working for me.. we have to remove the (convertview ==null)  line  from  both the getChildView and getGroupView .. the reason is, already created views are reused.. after removing this line all the views are getting recreated. eventhough, the view is already created.

Comment: thats the overhead for application but its good that your problem is solved lol :P

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
        .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

txtListChild.setText(childText);
txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(_context,"text clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
return convertView;
```

}